# Не обновляются записи в БД Laravel

Tags: база-данных, laravel, eloquent

Не могу понять почему, но записи в БД не обновляются... Все данные доходят, даже после метода save() если сделать дамп объекта, то данные из формы сохранены верно, а в самой БД изменений нет, к тому же это не первый метод обновления данных, делал магазины с аналогичным методом и все работало, даже в этом проекте метод редактирования категорий работает. Вот собственно метод:

```
 public function UpdateCountry(Request $request) {
   $Countries = Countries::where('Id',$request->get('Id'))->first();
   $Countries->Country = $request->get('Country');
   $Countries->Continent = $request->get('Continent');
   $Countries->Class = $request->get('Class');
   $Countries->save();
   return back()->with('status','Updated success!');

}
```

уже голову реально сломал.

Comment: Проверьте, что в таблице действительно существую поля в данном регистре. Для некоторых СУБД, регистр полей важен

Comment: Да, знаю это, с этим все ок

Comment: в моделе fillable поставили ?

Comment: Да, конечно. К тому же если бы не стоял fillable, то кидало бы ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему, она оказалась не такая уж и тяжелая, и нашел я её в моделе, нужно было всего лишь добавить:

```
protected $primaryKey = ['Id'];
```

Но я не мог подумать, что из-за этого возникнут проблемы.

Answer (score -1):

Или

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Так же можно перечислить реально те поля, которые модель не сможет оверлайднуть

Еще у вас в базе Id написан с большой буквы, eloquent будет искать id

Comment: Он будет искать те, которые указаны. Я указываю регистр...